# Acumatica: add underline for command field

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica

I have a text data field that should be an hyperlink.
That works fine:
[image]
But I cannot create it with underline as all other fields.
I can do it or as link or with underline:
[image]
The Form code looks like this:

```
  <px:PXFormView runat="server" ID="PXFormView1" DataSourceID="ds" DataMember="TaxationSummaryForAU" RenderStyle="Simple">
                    <Template>
                        <px:PXGroupBox runat="server" ID="gbSummary"
                            RenderStyle="RoundBorder"
                            RenderSimple="False"
                            Caption="Tax Declaration Summary"
                            DataField="IsAUJurisdiction" Style="margin: 15px;">
                            <Template>
                                <px:PXLayoutRule ID="PXLayoutRule21" runat="server" StartColumn="True" ControlSize="L" LabelsWidth="180" />

                                <px:PXTextEdit ID="edSummaryTFN" runat="server" DataField="TFNDescription" />

                                <px:PXTextEdit ID="edSummaryAustralianResident" runat="server" DataField="AustralianResidentDescription" />

                                <px:PXTextEdit ID="edTFT" runat="server" DataField="TaxFreeThresholdDescription" />

                                <px:PXTextEdit ID="edTFNDStatus" runat="server" DataField="TFNDStatus" />

                                <px:PXTextEdit ID="edTFNDLastSubmittedDate" runat="server" DataField="TFNDLastSubmittedDate" />

                                <px:PXTextEdit runat="server" DataField="STPBatch" ID="STPBatchEdit" Enabled="False">
                                    <LinkCommand Command="viewBatch" Target="ds"></LinkCommand>
                                </px:PXTextEdit>


                                <px:PXTextEdit ID="STPStatusEdit" runat="server" DataField="STPStatus" />


                                <px:PXLayoutRule ID="lrTFTCol" runat="server" StartColumn="True" ControlSize="L" LabelsWidth="M" />

                                <px:PXTextEdit ID="edOffsets" runat="server" DataField="OffsetsDescription" />

                                <px:PXTextEdit ID="edMediLevy" runat="server" DataField="MediLevyDescription" />

                                <px:PXTextEdit ID="edChildren" runat="server" DataField="ChildrenDescription" />

                                <px:PXTextEdit ID="edStudyDebt" runat="server" DataField="StudyDebtDescription" />

                                <px:PXTextEdit ID="edTaxScale" runat="server" DataField="TaxScaleDescription" />

                                <px:PXTextEdit ID="PXTextEdit2" runat="server" DataField="WitholdingVariation" />

                                <px:PXGroupBox runat="server" ID="PXGroupBox2" RenderStyle="Simple" RenderSimple="True" Caption="" DataField="ShowTFNDErrors" Style="margin-top: 25px; height: 200px;">
                                    <Template>
                                        <px:PXGrid runat="server" ID="grdEmployeeTFNDErrors" DataSourceID="ds" TabIndex="3100" SkinID="DetailsWithFilter" Width="100%"
                                            SyncPosition="true" KeepPosition="true" AutoAdjustColumns="True">
                                            <Levels>
                                                <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="EmployeeTFNDErrors">
                                                    <RowTemplate>
                                                        <px:PXLabel ID="edErrorField" runat="server" DataField="Concept" AutoRefresh="True" AllowEdit="False" />
                                                        <px:PXLabel ID="edErrorMessage" runat="server" DataField="ErrorMessage" AutoRefresh="True" AllowEdit="False" />
                                                    </RowTemplate>
                                                    <Columns>
                                                        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Concept" TextAlign="Left" Width="15px" />
                                                        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="ErrorMessage" TextAlign="Left">
                                                            <ValueItems MultiSelect="False" />
                                                        </px:PXGridColumn>
                                                    </Columns>
                                                </px:PXGridLevel>
                                            </Levels>
                                            <AutoSize Enabled="True" />
                                            <Mode AllowAddNew="True" AllowSort="False"></Mode>
                                            <ActionBar ActionsVisible="False" />
                                        </px:PXGrid>
                                    </Template>
                                </px:PXGroupBox>


                            </Template>
                        </px:PXGroupBox>

                    </Template>
                </px:PXFormView>
```

My field is:

```
  <px:PXTextEdit runat="server" DataField="STPBatch" ID="STPBatchEdit" Enabled="False">
                                <LinkCommand Command="viewBatch" Target="ds"></LinkCommand>
                            </px:PXTextEdit>
```

I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: i don't use acumatica, but surely in the asp form designer you can add underlining.  It should be a font property.   If not, you have options of manually adding a class that underlines the text, since it's all rendered to html.

Comment: Acumatica it is another world. I don't believe it is possible.

Comment: @John Lord, Both options are possible, John's answer cover the font property and mine the CSS class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think when you have Enable=false, you will not see the underline, but you can achieve this like below and make sure to unhide advanced properties to see these properties.

```
<px:PXTextEdit runat="server" DataField="STPBatch" ID="STPBatchEdit" Enabled="False">
<LinkCommand Command="viewBatch" Target="ds"></LinkCommand>
<Border>
<Bottom Color="#D2D4D7" Style="Solid" Width="1px" /></Border>
</px:PXTextEdit>
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this is the solution.
But where can I find the table and define the styles in the table-like way?

Comment: With user that has customizer rights. Press Control-Alt and click on the control to customize then use the popup window to open the customization project editor. It will open on the field to customize. If Control-Alt doesn't work you can access the shortcut in top right menu Customization->Inspect Element

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the `\App_Themes\Default` directory on the web server machine, you can modify the style for all disabled links.

The lack of underline occurs because of this style in the `\App_Themes\Default\00_Controls.css` :

```
a.Disabled {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Underline is a text decoration and this style removes it for disabled link. It's a deliberate design choice and you can comment out that style to get underline on disabled link editor controls:

```
a.Disabled {
  /*text-decoration: none;*/
}
```

With the default style, disabled link editor control have no text decoration:
[image]

When commenting the style, disabled link editor control have the default text decoration:
[image]

Comment: Hi, I put underline with through style and it worked, but as in your screenshot it defines underline only under the text, but not under control itself.

Comment: I applied the John's solution and it worked for me. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Yeah I noticed that afterward and up-voted John answer. There's something weird though, the gray underline (not the link one) is showing in all my instances for disabled link so I thought you meant underline link text. I wonder if it's just a rendering bug/glitch in old versions/browser etc... It's showing the gray line properly in my answer but not because of the CSS style. It just never hides it it seem.

Comment: I would agree that at least 19R1 the line shows in chrome. The original post based on purple color might be MYOB which currently is 18R1 I believe. Possible they have some change in their flavor of Acumatica which changes the control underline.

Comment: if you want to keep existing styling on everything but this page, you can override the existing css.  I don't recommend changing the default css since if you ever update the package your change will be overwritten.